# ASP.Net MVC Default Files Structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any functional reason of the default files structure on new ASP.Net MVC Application (Grouped by controllers, model, views etc. ?

Otherwise I would structure it in a way that would be more convenient for me.

Thanks!

Comment: The point of MVC is to separate concerns into Models, Views and Controllers.  Hence the organization...  Why not just use regular ASP.NET WebForms if you don't want MVC?

Comment: What way would be more convenient to you and why?

Comment: @Jim ; I don't use MVC for the separated folders

Comment: Since folders are based on the MVC pattern, I think there is no way to change it. If you are trying to create separation between modules within the application, look into MVC "Areas". As mentioned they too have same folder structure but they can be treated as different modules within one MVC application. And also they come with pain of hard coded url's while referencing them.

Comment: @Stefan P. I would group it by subject of views/model/controller
i.e.  
Client
    Controller  
    Models
    Views
    Scripts
Shared
    Scripts

Since we don't reuse models/views/controllers. The reason is pretty simple, I feel that navigating in the solution explorer from controllers to models to mappers etc is really overkill.

Comment: whats the size of your mvc app, how many models and controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you can put models and Controllers anywhere, since they're just code files that get compiled into a DLL.  Other files, however, have stricter location requirements if you want to take advantage of the conventions that MVC asssumes.

Strictly speaking, you can place views anywhere.  However, doing so has a number of consequences.  You must specify the full path to the view in your View() method, and if you don't put views in the ~Views folder, then it's possible for people to download them directly (which you don't want).

In general, MVC works a lot more smoothly if you follow the conventions.  If you go your own way, you lose a lot of automation and productivity.

Comment: Yeah, I get your point. But in my case, we spend more time on editing than creating files.

Comment: @zhealot - well, there's a lot of things that will frustrate you, even if you're not creating new views all the time.  I would strongly recommend you keep the views in the Views folder.  You're a little more flexible on structure below Views, but again you will have to use full paths if you go away from the Views/Controller/Action convention.

Comment: True enough. 
Thanks for your replies guys!